# Configure a custom object in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is there any way of configuration in spring security so , I can get my custom "USER" DAO class object while calling this code.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Comment: Your DAO object? Are you sure? Basically, you mean your "User" object (or whatever you're calling it)?

Comment: Yes the "User" dao object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it using `DaoAuthenticationProvider`

1. Ensure your `User` dao object extends `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`
2. Implement your `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`  and return your `User` dao object
3. Configure `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with your `UserDetailsService`

Comment: Should I configure it as a bean in the spring xml file

Comment: What configuration you use now? You should configure DaoAuthenticationProvider